# are half of "H2SO4 pH sample problem" webpages just wrong, or am I wrong?

Tags: acid-base

I did a Google search for "h2so4 pH sample problem" and went through the results, and it looks like about 50% of the webpages "explaining" how to do this problem give the wrong answer when calculating the pH of a solution of $\ce{H2SO4}$.  The incorrect sources either (a) assume that each molecule of $\ce{H2SO4}$ donates only one proton (approximately true only at high concentrations); or (b) assume that each molecule of $\ce{H2SO4}$ donates both protons (approximately true only at low concentrations).  Only about half of the sources do the problem correctly by assuming that all $\ce{H2SO4}$ molecules donate the first proton and then using the second dissociation constant to compute the degree of dissociation of the second proton.

I'm no expert, so am I missing something, or are half of the sources out there just wrong?

Googling "h2so4 pH sample problem", here are the first eight hits after removing pages that did not contain an $\ce{H2SO4}$ sample problem, and how I scored them:

- http://che1.lf1.cuni.cz/html/Calculations1112_II_handout.pdf -- says "For $\ce{H2SO4}$: $\ce{[H+]}$ = 2 $\times$ $\ce{[H2SO4]}$" -- incorrect.
- https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-calculate-pH-of-10-3-M-H2SO4 -- the top-voted answer also says the concentration of $\ce{[H+]}$ is twice the molarity of $\ce{[H2SO4]}$ which 0.001, which is incorrect.  (This gives the incorrect answer of pH = 2.69; the correct answer is 2.73.)
- https://chem.libretexts.org/Core/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry/Acids_and_Bases/Monoprotic_Versus_Polyprotic_Acids_And_Bases/Calculating_the_pH_of_the_Solution_of_a_Polyprotic_Base%2F%2FAcid -- uses the second dissociation constant correctly and an ICE chart -- correct
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gd8mYfiURx0 -- "Calculating the pH value of 1 M H2SO4" -- also assumes both protons are donated -- incorrect
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bfdbmT27L1c -- "Calculate pH of a Strong Acid" -- also assumes both protons are donated -- incorrect
- https://web2.0calc.com/questions/what-is-the-ph-of-a-0-00050m-solution-of-h2so4_1 -- uses the second dissociation constant -- correct
- [If the pH is zero, what would be the normality of a sulphuric acid solution?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6055/if-the-ph-is-zero-what-would-be-the-normality-of-a-sulphuric-acid-solution) -- I'm counting this as HALF-correct, because it is assumed that each $\ce{H2SO4}$ molecule donates only 1 proton.  This is approximately true at 1 M concentration, but I think it should be stated explicitly that the second proton doesn't get donated because the concentration is so high
- http://www.sparknotes.com/chemistry/acidsbases/phcalc/problems/ -- correctly explains the partial donation of the second proton, so even though they don't show the working out, it's still correct

So it looks like even for just a slightly-non-trivial problem, almost a majority of free online help resources get the answer wrong.  Is there some subtlety I'm overlooking?

Comment: And this is why I always told people to be careful about looking for help online. Personally, I've found that it's way worse that 50% for quantum mechanics problems...

Comment: Yes, you got it right. The web is dark and full of errors.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I see what you've done here :D Nice pun. BTW I'm afraid OP already asked about it earlier. This question is kinda waste of time. Question **is** trivial, and no idea why someone would even dig through all these pseudo "resources". Also difference between 2.69 and 2.73 as far as pH goes is negligible and approximate calculations are employed often. Approximation isn't equal to error as _every_ value describing physical world is approximate unless it's a constant made to be precise.

Comment: @Mithoron this is not the question I asked about earlier.  Earlier I mentioned on meta that 90% of online *automated pH calculators* give the wrong answer when computing for H2SO4 (because the creators forgot to include special-case code for a polyprotic acid).  In this case, I'm looking at free help resources where the authors actually worked out the problem by hand, so that reduced the chance of making a mistake, but still half of all the resources were wrong.

Comment: And, one of the reasons I document these things is because I get sick of people telling newbies, "All of this information is out there for free, go and google it and stop wasting our time," when the reality is that an extremely high proportion of resources that come up on Google are wrong.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's essentially a rant how people on internet are usually wrong, not a question.

Comment: I had read your meta post yesterday and was planning to convert this into a proper Q&A, however, this isn't the way I would have done it. Your question: "am I missing something, or are half of the sources out there just wrong?" has the obvious answer that the sources are wrong. In fact, you've labeled them as being incorrect or correct yourself. I fail to see what is being asked, thus.

Comment: @GaurangTandon note my meta post was about something slightly different; the meta post was about the fact that 8 out of 9 online "pH calculator" widgets get the wrong answer when calculating for sulfuric acid; this was about the fact that 4 out of 8 manually worked out sample problems get the wrong answer.  My adding the line "Am I missing something?" was not just a cheat way of turning it into a question :) I really did want to know if there was some subtlety I had overlooked.  Christopher Grayce had a good answer: there are often inaccuracies we overlook, like the auto-ionization of water...

Comment: @GaurangTandon ... even though, in this case I didn't agree with the overall point because the auto-ionization of water doesn't cause an error at two significant figures (whereas ignoring the second proton of H2SO4 does), but it did get me to at least think about it some more.  Regardless, since you said you had an idea for converting the "pH calculator" widgets question into a "proper Q&A", how would you have done it?

Answer (score 3):

...and you didn't even get into the fact that almost all explanations will ignore the autodissociation of water!

In some cases your online resources will be wrong, of course, and it would be odd to *expect* uniform correctness in something people donate for free on the Internet (including here BTW).  So that's worth keeping in mind.

However, it's also the case that it is not always *important* to treat a problem in all its subtlety.  For example, the difference you get in the calculated pH of 1M H2SO4 by treating or ignoring the second dissociation equilibrium is likely to be smaller than your measurement error in a typical undergraduate lab.  So why bother?  On the other hand, if you were running a very careful experiment with 0.01 M H2SO4 you might well want to take those other equilibria into account, and if you were doing something super sensitive with 10^-7 M H2SO4 then you'll need to worry about the autoionization of water, too.

Generally we use the least complex model that gets us the answer consistent with our measurement limitations.  That maximizes insight and reduces the obfuscation of complex calculation, which can easily make it so we fail to recognize an erroneous answer.   This runs all through science and engineering, and it's why simple models have such great staying power even when they are superseded by more sophisticated understanding.  Naturally a concomitant is that the good scientist must become very adept at identifying the least complex model he can use.  That takes deep insight into the limitations of each model, the probable sources of error, the limits of measurement, and the quality of data on hand.  Being good at this is a much more important skill in the senior scientist than mastering the details of the most complex and realistic model there is.

Comment: Well I figured that in most cases the question is asking about accuracy to two or three significant figures (that's what is used in the answers given), so you can ignore anything that's less significant than that (e.g. the auto-ionization of water), but you have to factor in anything that will make the answer incorrect at two-significant-figures accuracy (e.g., the second proton of H2SO4 at 0.001 M).

Comment: I agree if they are giving answers to more precision than is justified by the ignoring of the weak-acid equilibria, that is a significant mistake.  Goes back to the often neglected, boring, but important treatment of "appropriate precision" in calculated values.  All that sig dig stuff students hate, ha ha.